# mathematical notation for "optional" or "maybe" type

Tags: notation

In many programming languages, there is optional value. Optional type is used to indicate that the value maybe `nil` or `None`. For example python has `Optional[int]` and c++ has `std::optional<int>` type. I'd like to ask how to express such type in mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type

An example that I want to use optional type is in numerical optimization. Say you have numerical optimization solver function `solve` that takes input as problem descriptor $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and output the minimizer $x^* \in \mathbb{R}$ if the problem can be solved but return `nil` or `None` if not solved.

Of course, in almost all case, we can write the formal statement without using `Optional`. For example, in the above optimization example, setting $x^* = \infty$ or using whatever obviously invalid value to indicate that the optimization fails, which has been actually done in programming before optional type was introduced recently. But having optional type  make it easy to read the statement.

Comment: $solve : p \in R^n \Rightarrow \{ x^* \in R, \perp \}$

Comment: See nCatlab entry on partial map classifier. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+map+classifier